# SUMIFS in VBA formula using criteria

Tags: excel, formulas, sumifs, vba

I am relatively new to Excel VBA script and am having trouble with the syntax quotes here on this line

```
ActiveSheet.Range("H" & EndRowH + 2).Formula = "=SUMIFS(H2:H &EndRowH & ,C1:C1000,&"">=""&lngStart&)"
```

Let me know if you need any other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You had some basic string concatenation syntax errors.
2. Both the criteria range and the sum range need to be the same number of rows.

   ```
   ActiveSheet.Range("H" & EndRowH + 2).Formula = "=SUMIFS(H2:H" & EndRowH & ", C2:C" & EndRowH & ", "">=" & lngStart &""")"
   ```
3. Your original formula had the sum range start at H2 while the criteria range started at C1. While you can offset the sum range and the criteria range if necessary, they still have to be the same number of rows.

   ```
   ActiveSheet.Range("H" & EndRowH + 2).Formula = "=SUMIFS(H2:H" & EndRowH & ", C1:C" & EndRowH - 1 & ", "">=" & lngStart &""")"
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked like a charm. :) Thanks for the info too.

Comment: Yay!  (I didn't even notice the different range sizes; I was too focused on `"all"&" "&"the """&"quotes"&""""`...)

Comment: I am trying to add the second criteria and I am having the syntax error again.. Looked it multiple times and still not able to find it.   ActiveSheet.Range("H" & EndRowH + 10).Formula = "=SUMIFS(H2:H" & EndRowH & ", C2:C" & EndRowH & ", "">=" & lngStart & ", C2:C" & EndRowH & ", ""<=" & lngEnd & """)"